# Determinant of distance matrix of even cycle.

Tags: determinant

Any hints how to calculate this determinant? The result should be 0 (it's a determinant of distance matrix of a even length cycle).

$$\begin{vmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & k-1 & k & k-1 & \dots & 2 & 1\\ 
 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & \dots & k-2 & k-1 & k & \dots & 3 & 2\\
 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \dots & k-3 & k-2 & k-1 & \dots & 4 & 3\\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \vdots \\ 
k-1 & k-2 & k-3 & \dots & \dots & 0 & \dots & \dots & \dots & k-1 & k \\
k & k-1 & k-2 & \dots & \dots & \dots & 0 & \dots & \dots & k-2 & k-1 \\
k-1 & k & k-1 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & 0 & \dots & k-3 & k-2 \\
\vdots & & & & & & & & & \vdots \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \dots & k & k-1 & k-2 & \dots & 1 & 0 
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Is that a circulant matrix?

Comment: Looks like there are 4 circulant matrices... Making it a block matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we add the first row to the $(k+1)$-th row and add the second row to the $(k+2)$-th row then those two rows will be equal and so we can conclude the determinant is zero.